# Run IDE Script when new project is created (Intellij / Android Studio)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, plugins, scripting

I want to write a script or plugin that adds a few lines of code to the settings.gradle file of every new project that is created in Android Studio. I know that Android Studio shares pretty much the same scripting tools as Intellij IDEA, but I haven't been able to find a lot of relevant documentation anywhere that can help me.

So how can I go about detecting when a new project is created, and then append a few predetermined lines to a specific file?

Comment: You can try to save your project as template as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/saving-project-as-template.html and reuse it.

Comment: I want the solution to work on both Intellij IDEA and primarily Android Studio, but unfortunately the 'Save Project as Template' option is not available in the latter.